# Fancy Chapter Style

Tags: sectioning, chapters

I would like make a fancy chapter like the figure.

[image: Desired Output]

How can I produce like this one?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! Your question is interesting but the goal of this community is not necessarily for someone to "do it for you". Out of curiosity, what have you tried? Perhaps studying something like this (https://texblog.org/2012/07/03/fancy-latex-chapter-styles/) can help get you some ideas for where to start.